# PHP File Upload Size Issue

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload PDF file using PHP Script, The below is my code. It works perfectly for any file which is less than 1 MB, but when I upload more than 1 MB, It goes to the else statement and gives this message - "Max File Size Upload Limit Reached, Please Select Any Other File".

I have already seen php.ini configuration, this is set at 16M. Please help

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '16M');
            ini_set('post_max_size', '16M');
                //$ImageName=addslashes($_REQUEST['txtimagename']);
                //$ImageTitle=addslashes($_REQUEST['txtimagetitle']);
                $filepath="files/";
                
                //$filedt=date("dmYhisu")."_.".pathinfo($_FILES['imagefile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);                                                      
                $filedt=$_POST['vehregistration'].".".pathinfo($_FILES['imagefile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                
                //basename($_FILES['photoimg']['name']);
                $destination_img=$_POST['vehregistration'].".".pathinfo($_FILES['imagefile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                
                
                
                $filename=$filepath.$destination_img;
                                    
                //$filename=$filepath.basename($_FILES['Photo']['name']);
                //echo "$filepath".$_FILES[" imagefile "][" name "];
                
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagefile"]["tmp_name"], $filename))
                {
                    //echo $filedt;exit;
                    //rename($_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'],$filedt);
                    
                    return $filedt;
                }
                else
                {

                            echo "Max File Size Upload Limit Reached, Please Select Any Other File";
                }   
            }
```

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` check the *real* error

Comment: What setting set to 16M? You should set `upload_max_filesize = 16M` as well as `post_max_size = 16M` since you send it through POST request

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ini_set`use `$_FILES["imagefile"]["size"]`

```
$fileSize = $_FILES["imagefile"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$maxFileSz = 16777216; // set your max file size (in bytes) in this case 16MB
if($fileSize <= $maxFileSz) {
    // everything is okay... keep processing
} else {
    echo 'Max File Size Upload Limit Exceeded, Please Select Any Other File';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in else condition `$_FILES['imagefile']['error']` and see what is exact error . For more details http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php